# Make request to uClassify API via Node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to build a request for [uClassify](https://www.uclassify.com) API from Node. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code I've written:

```
  const req = JSON.stringify('Hello, my love!'); 
  const options = {
    body: req,
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uClassify/Sentiment/classify',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'MyKey'
    }
  };

  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error) {
      callback(response);
    }
  });
```

I get the following response:

```
statusCode: 400,
body: "{"statusCode":400,
        "message": "Error converting value \"Hello, my love!\" to
        type 'UClassify.RestClient.TextPayload'. Path '', line 1, position 17."}"
      }"
```

There's no clear instruction for JS in [the documentation](https://www.uclassify.com/docs/restapi), and I wonder whether I've implemented their example in cURL correctly in my `request` code.

> url -X POST -H "Authorization:Token YOUR_READ_API_KEY_HERE" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"texts\":[\"I am so happy
>   today\"]}" https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uClassify/Sentiment/classify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Node.js code your body is incorrect (but in your cURL you use the correct body). uClassify expects the object with property `texts`.
Change the body in your node.js code so:

```
const req = JSON.stringify({ texts: ['Hello, my love!'] }); 
const options = {
  body: req,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uClassify/Sentiment/classify',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'MyKey'
  }
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error) {
    callback(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried to set up `texts` property, but apparently I messed up syntax. There's also a thing, I have to pass token in a form of `Authorization: Token MyKey`. Cheers!